# Volley: Where do I find why Volley triggers certain errors?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to perfect my error handling in my app, but I can't find a centralized place where Volley triggers certain errors and why. For instance, I want to know that if the status code of my request is 500 or greater, than it will for sure trigger a ServerError, but I can't seem to find this documentation anywhere.

I've tried reading through source here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr1-dev-plus-aosp/src/com/android/volley

I can't seem to find anything though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the information that'll help!

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr1-dev-plus-aosp/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java

If you check out the performRequest method, you'll find everything you need. Requires a bit of dissecting, but that is where the meat is.

Also, [referenced HTTP Status Codes](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.java#HttpStatus.0SC_NOT_MODIFIED) will be useful for knowing exactly what comparisons are happening.